# How does the book document class ordinarily handle margins?

Tags: margins, geometry, documentclass

I wish to use the `geometry` package's `\newgeometry` (later on followed by `\restoregeometry`) in order to temporarily alter the margins of a document whose class is set to `book`. But I would like to produce something visually consistent with the ordinary margins of the `book` document class, even to a fine subliminal level; therefore, I do not wish to simply eyeball it. For this reason, I would like to know how exactly the `book` document class handles margins, if you do not alter them beyond calling the document class itself. I was having trouble finding documentation.

Comment: https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf#page=14

Comment: In general, if you go on [CTAN (Comprehensive TEX Archive Network)](https://ctan.org/pkg/book), most of the packages and classes documentations are contained on there

Comment: Instead of doing what you propose in your question, you could use `\savegeometry{bookdefault}`, `\newgeometry{...options...}` ... `\restoregeometry{bookdefault}` or `\loadgeometry{bookdefault}` and then not bother needing to know the default options etc, more is included in the `geometry` documentation on CTAN

Comment: @JamesT Thank you for your advice. I am in over my head with your first link. If what I am asking is complicated to perform, is there a way to simply take all four existing `book` margins (left, right, top, and bottom) and broaden them by a certain amount, say 5mm?

Comment: It depends on your font size, the margin values from most classes change depending on the fontsize of your document, are you planning to just use `10pt`, `11pt` in your document or?

Comment: @JamesT I am planning to use 11pt.